When I refresh the page my table style is not applied
I'm trying to create a table. When I click on the “generate” button, it inserts rows with data such as page title, date, actions...
The problem is that when I click it, it generates the rows with the style I've added. But when I refresh the page, the style is no longer applied.
public function woosterPartnerPluginSection()
{
?>
    <section class="presentation-content">
<?php
    do_settings_sections('wooster_gutenberg');
?>
            <h2>Générateurs de page</h2>
            <p>Choissisez le constructeur de page que vous préférez : </p> <?php
    do_settings_sections('wooster_form');
    // Conditionally display the buttons based on the presence and activation of Elementor plugin
    if ($this->ispluginElementorActive()) {
?>
            <!-- Display the buttons for both Gutenberg and Elementor -->
                <div style="display: flex;">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="submit-gutenberg" value="Gutenberg">
                        <input type="image" id="gutenberg_button" src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/Gutenberg.png', __FILE__); ?>" alt="Gutenberg" width=100% height=100% />
                    </form>
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="submit-elementor" value="Elementor">
                        <input type="image" id="elementor_button" src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/Elementor.png', __FILE__); ?>" width=100% height=100% />
                    </form>
                </div>

<?php 
    } else { 
?>
                <div style="display: flex;">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="submit-gutenberg" value="Gutenberg">
                        <input type="image" id="gutenberg_button" src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/Gutenberg.png', __FILE__); ?>" width=100% height=100% />
                    </form>
                </div>
<?php
}
?>

        <div class="results-info">
<?php
    $generated_pages = get_option('wooster_generated_pages', array());
    $num_generated_pages = count($generated_pages);
    echo 'Nombre de résultats : ' . $num_generated_pages;
?>
        </div>
        <div id="notification" class="notification">
            Page générée avec succès
        <table class="custom-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col" id="date" class="manage-column column-date">Titre</th>
                    <th scope="col" id="date" class="manage-column column-author">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col" id="constructor" class="manage-column column-author">Constructeur</th>
                    <th scope="col" id="actions" class="manage-column column-actions">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="generated-pages">
            </tbody>
        </table>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
function updatePageWithNewPost(data, buttonValue, postId) {
    const tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
    tableRow.id = 'post-' + data.id;
    tableRow.classList.add('custom-table-row');

    const titleCell = document.createElement('td');
    titleCell.textContent = data.title;

    const constructorCell = document.createElement('td');
    constructorCell.textContent = buttonValue;

    const dateCell = document.createElement('td');
    dateCell.textContent = data.date;

    const actionsCell = document.createElement('td');
    actionsCell.classList.add('actions');



    const viewButton = document.createElement('button');
    viewButton.classList.add('viewBtn');
    viewButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg"></i>';
    viewButton.dataset.previewUrl = data.previewUrl;

    viewButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const previewUrl = viewButton.dataset.previewUrl;
        window.location.href = previewUrl;
    });

    actionsCell.appendChild(viewButton);

    const editButton = document.createElement('button');
    editButton.classList.add('editBtn');
    editButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i>';
    editButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const editUrl = '<?php echo admin_url('post.php?action=edit&post='); ?>' + data.id;
        window.location.href = editUrl;
    });

    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.classList.add('deleteBtn');
    deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i>';
    deleteButton.dataset.postId = data.id;

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const postId = this.dataset.postId;
        const rowToDelete = this.closest('tr');

        if (confirm('Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer ce post ?')) {
            fetch('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                    body: 'action=delete_post&id=' + postId,
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.success) {
                        rowToDelete.remove();
                    } else {
                        console.error('Erreur lors de la suppression du post');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Erreur:', error);
                });
        }
    });

    actionsCell.appendChild(viewButton);
    actionsCell.appendChild(editButton);
    actionsCell.appendChild(deleteButton);

    tableRow.appendChild(titleCell);
    tableRow.appendChild(dateCell);
    tableRow.appendChild(constructorCell);
    tableRow.appendChild(actionsCell);

    document.getElementById('generated-pages').appendChild(tableRow);
    // const tableBody = document.getElementById('generated-pages');
    // tableBody.appendChild(tableRow);

}

const gutenbergButton = document.getElementById('gutenberg_button');
const elementorButton = document.getElementById('elementor_button');

const gutenbergForm = gutenbergButton.closest('form');
const elementorForm = elementorButton.closest('form');

const forms = [gutenbergForm, elementorForm];

forms.forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const buttonValue = form.querySelector('[type="hidden"]').value;
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        formData.append('action', 'create_post');

        fetch('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                updatePageWithNewPost(data, buttonValue, data.id);
                posts.push(data);
                showNotification();

            });

    });
});

to add the element , I use a loop and display all the data from $generated_pages. This is the row:
    public function display_generated_pages()
    {
        $generated_pages = get_option('wooster_generated_pages', array());
        $updated_pages = array();

        foreach ($generated_pages as $page) {
            $post = get_post($page['id']);
            if ($post) {
            if ($post && ($post->post_status == 'draft' || $post->post_status == 'publish')) {

                echo '<tr id="post-' . esc_attr($page['id']) . '" class="custom-table-row">';
                echo '<td>' . esc_html($page['title']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . esc_html($page['title']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . esc_html($page['date']) . '</td>';
                $constructor = '';
                if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'Gutenberg') {
                    $constructor = 'Gutenberg';
                } elseif (isset($_POST['submit-elementor']) && $_POST['submit-elementor'] === 'Elementor') {
                    $constructor = 'Elementor';
                }
                echo '<td>' . esc_html($constructor) . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="actions">';
                echo '<button class="viewBtn" data-preview-url="' . esc_url($page['previewUrl']) . '"><i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg"></i></button>';
                echo '<button class="editBtn"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i></button>';
                echo '<button class="deleteBtn" data-post-id="' . esc_attr($page['id']) . '"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg"></i></button>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';



                // Ajoutez la page existante à la liste mise à jour
                $updated_pages[] = $page;
            } elseif ($post->post_status != 'trash') {
                $updated_pages[] = $page;
            }
            }
        }

        // Mettez à jour l'option avec la liste des pages existantes
        update_option('wooster_generated_pages', $updated_pages);
    }

mytable

This is expected behaviour. HTTP is stateless. This means that any changes you make to the DOM after the page loads will be lost unless you manually persist those changes somewhere, eg. a database, local storage, sessions, cookies etc.

yes it is what I am trying to do, I have to use database and not Localstorage,sessions. I use wordpress, i retrieve the data in  $generated_pages = get_option('wooster_generated_pages', array()); but for the style I don't know how to do
